# Fibred product of sets $X\times_Z Y=\{(x,y)\in X\times Y: \alpha(x)=\beta(y)\}$ satisfies the universal property.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, products

This is Exercise 1.3.N from [Vakil's notes of Algebraic Geometry](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGdec2915public.pdf). The following is the diagram defining the universal property of fibred product:
[image]

> Show that in $\mathit{Sets}$,
>   $$X\times_Z Y=\{(x,y)\in X\times Y: \alpha(x)=\beta(y)\}.$$

**My attempt:**

Let $W$ be a set. Suppose there exist maps $\phi: W\rightarrow X$ and $\psi: W\rightarrow Y$, such that $\alpha\circ \phi=\beta\circ \psi$. We prove that there exists a unique map $\sigma: W\rightarrow X\times_Z Y$ such that $\beta\circ\text{Pr}_Y\circ \sigma=\beta\circ\psi$ and $\alpha\circ\text{Pr}_X\circ \sigma=\alpha\circ \phi$.

Obviously we can define $\sigma(w)=(\phi(w),\psi(w))$ and prove that it is well-defined and satisfies the equality.

**My question:**

I am stuck at the proof of uniqueness. Suppose another map $\tau(w)=(\tau_X(w), \tau_Y(w))$ also satisfies 
$$\beta\circ\text{Pr}_Y\circ \tau=\beta\psi,\\ \alpha\circ\text{Pr}_X\circ\tau=\alpha\phi.$$

So I end up with 
$$\beta\circ\tau_Y=\beta\circ \psi,\\
\alpha\circ\tau_X=\alpha\circ \phi.$$

But these do not necessarily imply $\tau_Y=\psi$ and $\tau_X=\phi$, which is what I want to show. Since the maps are all through $\alpha$ and $\beta$, there seems no way to get rid of them. How to proceed?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\Pr_X \circ~ \tau = \phi$ and $\Pr_Y \circ~ \tau = \psi$. So $\tau_X = \phi$ and $\tau_Y = \psi$.

Hence $\tau = (\tau_X, \tau_Y) = (\phi, \psi) = \sigma$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But why is that $Pr_Y \circ~ \tau = \psi$ and $\Pr_X \circ~ \tau = \phi$? I know that $\beta\circ Pr_Y \circ~ \tau =\beta\circ \psi$, but why can we cancel the $\beta$?

Comment: That a diagram commutes means that any two chains starting and ending at the same place are equal. I did not cancel the $\beta$, I just didn't use it.

Comment: I see! That clarifies it! Thank you!